# Not getting concept of null

Tags: mysql

Hy Guys,

Beginning with mysql. I am not able to grasp the concept of NULL. Check screen-shot (*declare_not_null, link*). In it when I specifically declared 'name' field to be NOT NULL. When i run the 'desc test' table command, the table description shows default value for name field to be NULL.Why is that so?

From what I have read about NULL, it connotes a missing or information that is not applicable. So when I declare a field to be NOT NULL it implies (as per my understanding) that user must enter a value for the name field else the DB engine should generate an error i.e. record will not be entered in DB. However when i run 'insert into test value();' the DB engine enters the record in table. Check screen-shot(*empty_value, link*).

**FLICKR LINKS**
*declare_not_null*
http://www.flickr.com/photos/55097319@N03/5302758813/

*empty_values*
*Check the second screenshot on flickr*

*Q.2* what would be sql statemetn to drop a primary key from a table's field.
If I use 'ALTER TABLE test drop key id;' it gives the following:

**ERROR:**
Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key.

Thanks for your help..

Comment: +1 for the question. That behavior is new to me... Also you might want to consider asking another question for dropping an `auto_increment` primary key.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Here are a few tips to help you get the most out of this site: 1) Please don't link to images on flickr - include them inline. 2) Please don't post text as images - post it as text. 3) If you have two different questions create two different questions. Don't try to create one monolithic question. More often than not it results in people only answering part of your question or else very brief answers that cover everything but in not much detail.

Comment: Ok I take that advice...

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the default value column. The database won't let you update or insert that column with `null`.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take the first question:

> When i run the 'desc test' table command, the table description shows default value for name field to be NULL.Why is that so?

The default being NULL means either:

- You have specified that the default is NULL *or*
- You haven't specified a default value for that column.

In this case it is the second option. It does *not* mean that it is possible to insert a NULL.

Comment: but if u want to enter an empty strings it is entered as double quotes "" or single quotes '' with nothing in between...so i suppose by running 'insert into test value();' i am NOT entering empty strings in fields declared as NOT NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Q.1. I don't have access to Flickr so I can't see your screenshots, anyway, if you declare a column NOT NULL, there may be a default value for this column set, and that is why you can add a record.

Q.2. Looks like you cannot have an auto increment column that is not a Primary Key. So if you want to drop the Primary Key, you need to drop the auto increment first.